# What happens if the trivial representation is the only irreducible representation?

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose we have that the trivial representation is the only irreducible representation. I am trying to understand what this would imply for any given representation $(V, \phi).$ Couple of questions:

1. If $V$ is a degree 1 representation does this mean that $V$ is the trivial representation? Clearly this should be true as $V$ has no proper subspaces but is this true in general? I.e., are there degree one representations that are not trivial?
2. Suppose $V$ is of degree $n > 1.$ Does this mean that we can reduce $V$ to $V_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus V_n$ such that $V_i = ke_i$ is of degree one and that for every $g \in G, ge_i = e_i?$

Comment: Yes to the first one, no to the second (think of upper triangular matrices with $1$s on the diagonal with coefficients in a finite field and representations over the algebraic closure of that field).

Comment: For 2. it will depend on your assumptions regarding $|G|$ and the characteristic of the field.

Comment: @Max But if you do put some assumptions that make it true, then you immediately get $|G| = 1$ which make them unnecessary anyway.